# Coprime Factorization in Python

Tags: python

I have to write a code to find the two highest co prime factors of an entered number, 10^num.

Right now, I've written:

```
def coprimes(num):
    for x in range (2, num):
        for y in range (2, num):
            while (gcd(x,y) == 1) & (x != y):
                if (x*y==num):
                    return (x,y)
```

Which is obviously a really slow program because of the forloops. Whenever I enter it into the terminal, it's too slow to produce an answer. I'm also not sure if this is correct. Do you have any suggestions on how I could improve this method?

An example answer of this method should be:

```
>>> coprimes(10)
(9765625, 1024)
```

Comment: In what sense is a pair of coprime factors the highest?

Comment: And how the heck are 9765625 and 1024 supposed to be factors of 10?

Comment: I think you mean `and`, not `&`.

Comment: My bad, I meant that it's supposed to be 10^num.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want

```
return 2**num, 5**num
```

Note that the question is ill-defined - it's not clear whether `2**num, 5**num` should be considered higher than `1, 10**num`. However, those pairs of factors are higher than any other.

To arrive at this answer, note that at most 1 of the factors can be divisible by 2, and at most 1 of the factors can be divisible by 5. If one factor is divisible by both 2 and 5, the other must be 1, and any integer is coprime to 1. If one factor is divisible by 2 and the other by 5, we pick the highest powers of 2 and 5 possible. (Options where 2 or 5 divide neither number produce lower factors.)